# Parsing XML file (java)

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have this XML file(Param.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<param-config>

    <parameter>
        <tag> BNsprate  </tag>
        <value> 0.8 </value>
    </parameter>

    <parameter>
        <tag> CellId_nbr  </tag>
        <value> 1 </value>
    </parameter>

    <parameter>
        <tag> Calls_nbr  </tag>
        <value> 2 </value>
    </parameter>

    <parameter>
        <tag> Call_time  </tag>
        <value> 00:02:00 </value>
    </parameter>

    <parameter>
        <tag> InCalls_nbr  </tag>
        <value> 0 </value>
    </parameter>

    <parameter>
        <tag> Sms_nbr  </tag>
        <value> 0 </value>
    </parameter>


</param-config>
```

I wrote this java code to print this file content :

```
  private String paramReader(String tag) {

    String value = "";
    try {

        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("Param.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter");

        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(i);
            System.out.println(nNode.getNodeValue());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("tag").item(0)
                        .getTextContent() == tag) {

                    value = eElement.getElementsByTagName("value").item(0)
                            .getTextContent();
                }
            }
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;

}
```

This returns :
null
null
null
null
null
null
Please, I'm asking why it just reads the file whithout getting content values?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Modified version is below**. This will fetch the text content of value node of input tag node.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

/**
 * @author JayaPrasad
 * 
 */
public class ParseXml {

    private String paramReader(String tag) {

        String value = "";
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse("parse.xml");

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter");

            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(i);
//              NodeList childNodes = nNode.getChildNodes();
//              for (int j = 0, length = childNodes.getLength(); j < length; j++) {
                // System.out.println(childNodes.item(j).getNodeName() + ":"
//                   + childNodes.item(j).getTextContent());
//                  if (childNodes.item(j).getNodeName().equals(tag)) {
//                      value = childNodes.item(j).getTextContent();
//                       System.out.println("Tag Node Value ::: " + value);
//                  }
//              }

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = null;
                    if (nNode instanceof Element) { // Safest way before casting
                        eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    }

                    if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("tag").item(0)
                            .getTextContent().trim().equals(tag)) {

                        value = eElement.getElementsByTagName("value").item(0)
                                .getTextContent();
                        System.out.println("Result value :: " + value);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParseXml xmlObj = new ParseXml();
        xmlObj.paramReader("Call_time");
    }

}
```

Comment: @user3510024 wat is the actual problem? Which node value you require?

Comment: I want exactly to print "value", but the problem is that it prints nothing(I mean that "value" is null. What do you think?

Comment: @user3510024 i have modified your code a little. The program reads the file with content value.

Comment: Thank you so much, every thing is ok.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing String to a String using equality sign, while you should use .equals method here:

```
if(eElement.getElementsByTagName("tag").item(0).getTextContent()==tag){
```

instead it should be like this:

```
if(eElement.getElementsByTagName("tag").item(0).getTextContent().equals(tag)){
```

`==` sign checks equality of the reference, i.e. returns true if both reference the same object in memory, while you want to check the equality of value, which is what `.equals()` method does.

Comment: Thank you. But it dosen't resolve the problem, the problem is that I can't print different values of "nNode". "nList" is empty that's exactly the problem. Because it contains 6 null elements.

Answer (score 1):

For XML parsing and back again you should have to use `XStream` API. It is very easy to manipulate.Check this link

http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html